# sql server stored procedures inserted value as output parameter

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm transforming a query into my first stored procedure but have not find solution for one step.

here FULL Procedure

```
UPDATE Procedure dbo.sp_BOOK 
@U nvarchar(50),
@P nvarchar(50),
@T nvarchar(50),
@D datetime , 
@O nvarchar(10), 
@S nvarchar(50),
@R nvarchar(50) OUTPUT

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ID int;

IF EXISTS
(
    select d.name
    from users s
    join users g on CHARINDEX(s.UserID,g.ParentOf)>0
    join booking b on charindex(s.ClassRoom,b.class)>0
    join interview w on b.id=w.bookingID
    join users d on d.userid=b.teacherID
    where (g.UserID=@U and g.Password=@P and b.active='1' and g.Role='parent' and b.teacherID=@T and w.Time=@O and w.studentID=@S and b.[Day]=@D )  
)
    begin
        update w set w.Active= ~ w.Active output 'OK/'+cast(inserted.Active as nvarchar) rspn
        from users s
        join users g on CHARINDEX(s.UserID,g.ParentOf)>0
        join booking b on charindex(s.ClassRoom,b.class)>0
        join interview w on b.id=w.bookingID
        join users d on d.userid=b.teacherID
        where (g.UserID=@U and g.Password=@P and b.active='1' and g.Role='parent' and w.Time=@O and b.[Day]=@D );


    end
ELSE
    begin
        IF EXISTS
        (
            select d.name
            from users s
            join users g on CHARINDEX(s.UserID,g.ParentOf)>0
            join booking b on charindex(s.ClassRoom,b.class)>0
            join interview w on b.id=w.bookingID
            join users d on d.userid=b.teacherID
            where (g.UserID=@U and g.Password=@P and b.active='1' and g.Role='parent' and b.teacherID=@T and w.time=@O and b.[Day]=@D and w.active='1' )
        )
            begin
                SET @R='KO/booked already'
                --select 'KO/booked already from other' rspn
            end
        ELSE
            begin
                IF EXISTS
                (
                    select 1
                    from interview w
                    join users s on s.userID=w.StudentID
                    join users g on charindex(w.studentID,g.ParentOf)>0
                    join booking b on charindex(s.classroom,b.class)>0
                    join users d on d.UserID=b.TeacherID
                    where (g.UserID=@U and g.Password=@P and b.active='1' and g.Role='parent' and w.Time=@O and b.Day=@D and w.active='1')                  
                )
                    begin
                        --select 'KB/you are busy at this Time!' rspn
                        SET @R='KB/you are busy'
                    end
                ELSE
                    begin
                        IF EXISTS
                        (
                            select d.name
                            from users s
                            join users g on CHARINDEX(s.UserID,g.ParentOf)>0
                            join booking b on charindex(s.ClassRoom,b.class)>0
                            join interview w on b.id=w.bookingID
                            join users d on d.userid=b.teacherID
                            where (g.UserID=@U and g.Password=@P and b.active='1' and g.Role='parent' and b.teacherID=@T and w.studentID=@S and b.[Day]=@D )                            
                        )
                            begin
                                --select 'KZ/You already booked with teacher fro this child' rspn
                                SET @R='KZ/You already booked'
                            end
                        ELSE
                            begin
                                IF NOT EXISTS
                                (
                                    select 1 from booking where TeacherID=@T and [Day]=@D
                                )
                                    begin 
                                        begin Transaction
                                          Insert into booking (TeacherID,Materie,Class,[day],TimeFrame,Duration, DateFrom, DateTo) select @T, r.Materie, r.classi, @D, '0900-1000' , durata, getdate(), dateadd(d,anticipo*-1,@D) from ricevimentoD r join users u on r.TeacherID=u.UserID  where Teacherid=@T

                                          set @ID= (select ID  from booking where teacherID=@T and [Day]=@D)

                                          insert into Interview (BookingID, Time, studentID)  VALUES ( @ID,@O,@S)
                                          SET @R='OK/Registered New'
                                        commit
                                    end
                                ELSE
                                    begin
                                        set @ID= (select ID  from booking where teacherID=@T and [Day]=@D)

                                        insert into Interview (BookingID, Time, studentID) VALUES ( @ID,@O,@S)
                                        SET @R='OK/Registered Old'
                                    end
                            end
                    end
            end
    end
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

...........

problem is transform

```
OUTPUT 'OK/'+CAST(insterted.Active as nvarchar) rspn
```

into something that put the value in `@R`, but have no idea how to do it

I googled a lot but have not find the solution :-(

can give me some indication

Thanks!

Sergio

Comment: what if more that one row is updated

Comment: @NoDisplayName Well, one would hope that the column `dbo.Users.UserID` is a primary key and would only have one match for a scalar parameter (`UserID = @U`).

Comment: @AaronBertrand thats one theory, But what if that one single `userid` is present more than once in `booking table`

Comment: @NoDisplayName if you follow through the where clause, they would also have to have multiple interviews on the same day at the same time.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for answer..
actually the procedure is much longer than what showed and are controls to avoid to have more than one interview for the same student in that day, to avoid the teacher to have more than 1 interview at same time and to avoid that parent have more than 1 interview at that time, but problem was on that specific point so I posted only the first third of the procedure.

Comment: Now I added the full SP..
as you can see for the latter values has been easy to pass the desired value to @R but I do not know to pass the inserted.Active value of the Update Statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a table variable and OUTPUT INTO temp_Table

Something like this....

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @ID int;
DECLARE @ID_TABLE TABLE (ID VARCHAR(100))

IF EXISTS
(
    select d.name
    from users s
    join users g on CHARINDEX(s.UserID,g.ParentOf)>0
    join booking b on charindex(s.ClassRoom,b.class)>0
    join interview w on b.id=w.bookingID
    join users d on d.userid=b.teacherID
    where (g.UserID=@U and g.Password=@P and b.active='1' and g.Role='parent' 
            and b.teacherID=@T and w.Time=@O and w.studentID=@S and b.[Day]=@D )  
)
    begin
        update w 
         set w.Active= ~ w.Active 
        output 'OK/'+cast(inserted.Active as nvarchar) INTO @ID_TABLE(ID)
        from users s
        join users g on CHARINDEX(s.UserID,g.ParentOf)>0
        join booking b on charindex(s.ClassRoom,b.class)>0
        join interview w on b.id=w.bookingID
        join users d on d.userid=b.teacherID
        where (g.UserID=@U and g.Password=@P and b.active='1' and g.Role='parent' 
                  and w.Time=@O and b.[Day]=@D );

-- select the ID into a variable or return a table execute one of the following
   SELECT @ID = ID FROM @ID_TABLE  --<-- If it will only return a single value
   SELECT * FROM @ID_TABLE         --<-- If it can update multiple rows at a time
    end
```

Comment: Hi!
Well since it will modify only 1 record a time no need to use a table

But the solution proposed does requires that the parameters of last select has to have the same parameters as the previous update..

But I was looking for a simple solution since we already have the value in the update.. there should be the way to export such value without querying again..

now I added the full SP perhaps is more clear
Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that you have adequate unique constraints defined in your database to enforce this also.

Comment: @Joe output into syntax can only insert records into a table, so whether you are updating one or multiple records you will need a table variable to get the values from output clause.